# pyTelegramBotAPI

Tags: python, telegram

Для бота телеграмма использую библиотеку `pyTelegramBotAPI (v. '3.2.0')` на `Python 3.5`.
При отправке сообщения возникает непонятная пауза

```
currenttime = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", time.localtime())
print(currenttime, 'Начинаем отсылать сообщение')
tb.send_message(chat_id, txt, reply_markup=markup)
currenttime = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", time.localtime())
print(currenttime, 'Заканчиваем отсылать сообщение')
```

В `Shell` это выглядит так:

```
2016-03-08 01:14:55 Начинаем отсылать сообщение
2016-03-08 01:15:00 Начинаем отсылать сообщение
```

Проблема только при работе приложения на сервере, с локали все уходит моментом.
Аналогичная картина для `tb.send_chat_action(chat_id, 'typing')`.
Если с этого же сервера шлю сообщение на `api.telegram.org` через, например, MS SQL, то они так же доходят моментом.